# Combining/merging values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas-groupby

I have multiple values for a single class in a column and I want to combine/merge them. I have tried the following code but it just merges values based on each grade.

```
df.groupby('Grades')['Students'].apply(' '.join).reset_index()
```

I do not want it. Let's assume we have the following DataFrame:

```
+----------------------------------+--------+
|             Students             | Grades |
+----------------------------------+--------+
| Student1                         |      0 |
| Student1                         |      1 |
| Student1                         |      2 |
| Student2                         |      3 |
| Student2                         |      5 |
| Student2                         |      0 |
| Student3                         |      1 |
| Student3                         |      0 |
| Student3                         |      0 |
+----------------------------------+--------+
```

and I want to have the following DataFrame:

```
+----------------------------------+--------+
|             Students             | Grades |
+----------------------------------+--------+
| Student1                         |      1 |
| Student2                         |      3 |
| Student3                         |      0 |
+----------------------------------+--------+
```

where I want to merge students and take one of his/her grades randomly. Even if there are more columns other than grades I want them to be selected randomly for each student when I merge them.

Comment: Question has actually nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first glance, I found two ways to accomplish the same task, but there may be many others.

The first one shuffles the entire DataFrame and for each group (Student's grades) takes the first (random) row:

```
df.sample(frac=1.0).groupby("Students").first().reset_index()
```

The second approach, instead, randomly takes one row for each student (thus avoiding the shuffling of the entire dataset):

```
df.groupby("Students").apply(lambda x: x.sample(n=1)).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should look at :

```
df.sample(frac=1.0)\
    .groupby(['Students']) \
    .agg(any_grades = ('rnd_grade','first'),
         any_other_col = ('other_col','first')) \
    .reset_index()
```

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.any.html), `np.any` tests whether any array element along a given axis evaluates to True and returns a boolean, not a random element of the group.

Comment: Oh right, well a 'first' with a shuffle before should do the trick. Kinda dissapointing that pandas doesn't offer an any() aggregation func tho